# copy to clipboard using jquery and jquery.copy-to-clipboard.js issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

I am using a jQuery script (copy-to-clipboard.js) to copy some text to the clipboard and then paste it somewhere else.

The page containing the rows that I need to copy is loaded from a database.

The script works well even after deleting some rows from the database and removing it from the page using Ajax calls.

It stops working when I dynamically add a new row to the page with using an Ajax call.

My guess is that I need to wrap the code or the element in someway but I don't know how. Could you help me, please?

This is my jQuery code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.a_copy_img').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('#tlist > tr:first').find('td.text').CopyToClipboard();
      });
  });
</script>
```

This is the part of the page that initially shows the table with the rows (and it works at first):

```
<div class="my-2">
            <table class="table">
              <thead class="bg-light">
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">Immagine</th>
                  <th scope="col">Data</th>
              <th scope="col">Copia</th>
                  <th scope="col">Cancella</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="tlist">
                <?php

                  $html = '';
                  $c = new Myclass();
                  $html = $c->list_imgs($pdo);
                  echo $html;

                ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
</div>
```

This is part of the function that shows the row of the table above:

```
$this->html .= '<tr><th class="no_text" scope="row">' . $this->row['id'] . '</th><td class="text">' . $this->row['foto'] . '</td><td class="no_text">' . $this->row['reg_date'] . '<td class="text-center"><a class="a_copy_img" title="copia immagine" data-clipboard-target=".text" href="#" rel="' . $this->row['id'] . '"' . '><i class="fa fa-clone" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>' . '<td class="text-center"><a class="a_trash_img" title="cancella immagine" href="#" rel="' . $this->row['id'] . '"' . '><i class="fas fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>' . '</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I was close to the solution and indeed here it is the right jquery code to solve the problem:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).on("click", ".a_copy_img", function(){
          $(this).parents('#tlist > tr:first').find('td.text').CopyToClipboard();
        });
    });
  </script>
```

The solution was to bind the event to the document and now it works also with element added dinamically.

So hope it will help someone out there looking for a solution to this problem or something similar to it.